# Ajax Form Submit w/ preventDefault() always hits Success

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I've got a .NET MVC app.  In one of the views, there is a modal.  Inside the modal, there is a form.

A few notes...

- Because the form is inside a modal, I'm trying to use a little ajax to prevent the form from doing the default submission.
- The form itself is inside a partial view
- I'm using standard, built-in MVC validation scripts along with the data annotations in the partial view's model.  Example:

  ```
  [Display(Name = "Address")]
  [Required()]
  [StringLength(200)]
  public string Address { get; set; }
  ```

This is the script I'm trying to use to prevent the default submission:

```
        $(function () {
            var frm = $('#form-accountprofileedit');
            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('ok');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

When the submit button is clicked and required fields are empty, I need the validation messages displayed.  But, instead, the 'ok' dialog box pops up, indicating the validation was successful.

What am I doing wrong?

(I can post more code, if needs be.)

**EDIT AFTER:**

Here's the form (slimmed down):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AccountProfileEdit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-accountprofileedit", @class = "full-form" }))
    {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.CustomTextboxFor(model => model.Address)

    <div style="text-align:right;">
        <button type="submit" id="accountprofileedit-submit" name="accountprofileedit-submit" value="Edit Account" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:5px;">Edit Account</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What does your cshtml look like to build just the form?  This question is currently impossible to answer.

Comment: I edited the OP with the form. Thanks!

Comment: What is CustomTextboxFor? I see no validation on your form, only a validation summary. What kind of HTML does this CustomTextboxFor helper emit?

Comment: It's just an HTML Helper. Pretty much same thing as a normal TextBox For.  <input id="Address" name="Address" value="" maxlength="200" type="text">

Comment: I don't understand when you say, "I see no validation on your form."  The validation is in the model.  Standard MVC.  No?

Comment: Did you make sure [unobtrusive validation is enabled](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that irrespective of whether the `ModelState` is valid the controller is always going to return a 200(OK) status when you return the partial view from the Post action. You can override this by setting the response status code.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return PartialView("_FormBody", model);
}
```

You then need to replace the form body with the response from the server in order to show the validation messages.

```
$(function () {
    var frm = $('#form-accountprofileedit');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $('#form-accountprofileedit').html(xhr.responseText);
        }
        });
    });
}
```

Note: do not replace the whole of the form element otherwise you will remove your submit handler.